# How to extract function on a `v-for` table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Noob here. I am trying to build a dropdown for only the `div` id matches my specific name.

For example, my table column names are : A, B, C.

I only want to enable dropdown for column A

My table is a template that looks like follows:

```
template(v-for="field in tableFields")
   th(:id="'_' + field.name")

   select(v-if="field.name ==='A'" v-model="selectedScope"
   option
   option(v-for="scope in scopes" v-bind:value="scope" ) {{scope}}
```

This works but i want to extract the `v-if="field.name ==='A'"` to a function.

I have the following but it didn't work:

```
template(v-for="field in tableFields")
   th(:id="'_' + field.name")

   select(v-if="shouldProvideSelectOption(field)" v-model="selectedScope"
   option
   option(v-for="scope in scopes" v-bind:value="scope" ) {{scope}}
```

And under `computed`, i have something like this:

```
    computed: {
        shouldProvideSelectOption: function (field) {
            return field.name === 'A'
        }
    },
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a method instead of computed property :

```
methods : {
    shouldProvideSelectOption: function (field) {
        return field.name === 'A'
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Like @RoyJ said in the comment below :

*computeds do not take arguments (except for setters). A computed is used like a variable*

Comment: Note why: computeds do not take arguments (except for setters). A computed is used like a variable.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks for this detail i added that in my answer